# If I dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 will my files that are not related to the Operating System stay on that PC

Tags: dual-boot

If I install Ubuntu 16.04 to run along with Windows 8 will my personal files such as Steam, Antivirus, and documents be deleted?

Comment: If you install it correctly, no.

Comment: Best to use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk to repair for the size change. Do not make too small as NTFS really likes at least 30% free space in partition. Make sure fast start up or Windows always on hibernation is turned off.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 3):

No. That's the whole point of a dual-boot: to keep one OS intact, while also having another OS installed alongside the first.

*Be careful, though.* Make sure that you are choosing the right option (the `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows` option). This will shrink the Windows partition to half its original size and install Ubuntu in the newly created space. Do ***not*** choose ***any*** options that include the word `erase` or `wipe` or any synonym of either.

If there is no option for a dual-boot, you will have to do some somewhat advanced partitioning and options. They aren't difficult, but they can easily be messed up. If you run into the problem of only seeing `Wipe Hard Drive and Install Ubuntu` and `Something Else...` as options, comment and I can provide you with an existing Q&A. Please don't ask a new question about it, as it will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are planning on implementing the dual boot. As long as you do not delete your Windows 8 partition (or whatever partition those files are on) your files will not be affected.